# Python : Combining the values of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I am struggling to combine the values of two arrays in Python. I want to get the values of two arrays as pairs.
EXAMPLE: Suppose we have two arrays `a` and `b` as below:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 3, 1]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][j], end=' ')
    print() 

b = [[4, 0, 3], [6, 3, 6], [1, 4, 1]]

for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        print(b[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

How can I combine the values of two arrays as pairs similar to:

```
array([[(1,4), (2,0), (3,3)],
       [(4,6), (5,3), (6,6)],
       [(0,1), (3,4), (1,1)]])
```

I am not sure if it can be done as an array or a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine list comprehension and [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to do that:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 3, 1]]
b = [[4, 0, 3], [6, 3, 6], [1, 4, 1]]

c = [ list(zip(a[x],b[x])) for x in range(len(a))] # works b/c len(a) = len(b)

print(c)
```

Output

```
[[(1, 4), (2, 0), (3, 3)], [(4, 6), (5, 3), (6, 6)], [(0, 1), (3, 4), (1, 1)]]
```

This works correctly as `a` and `b` have the same amount of inner lists *and* the inner lists have the same length. `zip()` does only create tuples for 2 lists up to the shorter length of both. For inequeal length lists you can use [`itertools.zip_longest(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which uses `None` or a specified default to fill up the shorter list.

Comment: Or `[list(zip(*x)) for x in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski like yours better.